# Interchanging rows in Numpy produces an embedded array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, subset

I'm trying to interchange the rows of np.array `A` using the following array:

```
A = np.array([[0,-3,-6,4,9],
             [-1,-2,-1,3,1],
             [-2,-3,0,3,-1],
             [1,4,5,-9,-7]])
```

When I use the following code:

```
A = np.array([A[3],A[0],A[1],A[2]])
```

my array becomes

```
array([[ 1,  4,  5, -9, -7],
       [ 0, -3, -6,  4,  9],
       [-1, -2, -1,  3,  1],
       [-2, -3,  0,  3, -1]])
```

like I hoped, wished and dreamed. When I try a broader slice, though (as I would need for larger matrices), it doesn't work quite as well:

```
A = np.array([A[3], A[0:3]])
A

array([array([-2, -3,  0,  3, -1]),
       array([[ 1,  4,  5, -9, -7],
       [ 0, -3, -6,  4,  9],
       [-1, -2, -1,  3,  1]])], dtype=object)
```

Why is this happening/how can I correctly perform this slice?

Comment: Use `np.roll` : `np.roll(A,1,axis=0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `vstack`:

```
In [5]: np.vstack([A[3], A[0:3]])                                                               
Out[5]: 
array([[ 1,  4,  5, -9, -7],
       [ 0, -3, -6,  4,  9],
       [-1, -2, -1,  3,  1],
       [-2, -3,  0,  3, -1]])
```

Answer (score 3):

The first expression can be written much more simply as

```
A = A[[3, 0, 1, 2], :])
```

The second can therefore be written as

```
A = A[[3, *range(3)], :]
```

This is more general than using `roll`, since you can move an arbitrary row with something like

```
A = A[[1, *range(1), *range(2, 4)], :]
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.roll` as commented is probably the best choice. You could also use `np.r_`:

```
A[np.r_[3,0:3]]
```

Out:

```
array([[ 1,  4,  5, -9, -7],
       [ 0, -3, -6,  4,  9],
       [-1, -2, -1,  3,  1],
       [-2, -3,  0,  3, -1]])
```